# odoo throwing an error when trying to inherit model from other module

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I am trying to inherit products.products from website_sale module, to change some of the properties there. But there is an error, when I try to inherit it.
Code from the my module's models.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api


class imgtogif_r(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'
    _name = 'product.product'
#     _description = 'imgtogif_r.imgtogif_r'

#     name = fields.Char()
#     value = fields.Integer()
#     value2 = fields.Float(compute="_value_pc", store=True)
#     description = fields.Text()
#
#     @api.depends('value')
#     def _value_pc(self):
#         for record in self:
#             record.value2 = float(record.value) / 100
```

Module was made using odoo's scaffold method. Server crash(Bellow is the error log and in browser it is error 500) occours only when I try to add _inherit in my models.py

Error log:

```
2020-05-09 10:51:49,361 15798 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 13.0-20200509 
2020-05-09 10:51:49,361 15798 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /etc/odoo/odoo.conf 
2020-05-09 10:51:49,361 15798 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons', '/var/lib/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/13.0'] 
2020-05-09 10:51:49,362 15798 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo@default:default 
2020-05-09 10:51:49,469 15798 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports. 
2020-05-09 10:51:49,526 15798 WARNING ? odoo.addons.base.models.res_currency: The num2words python library is not installed, amount-to-text features won't be fully available. 
2020-05-09 10:51:49,546 15798 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on raitis-VirtualBox:8069 
2020-05-09 10:51:52,515 15798 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files 
2020-05-09 10:51:52,523 15798 INFO odoodb odoo.modules.loading: loading 1 modules... 
2020-05-09 10:51:52,532 15798 INFO odoodb odoo.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries 
2020-05-09 10:51:52,547 15798 INFO odoodb odoo.modules.loading: loading 58 modules... 
2020-05-09 10:51:52,551 15798 WARNING odoodb odoo.modules.loading: Transient module states were reset 
2020-05-09 10:51:52,551 15798 ERROR odoodb odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 60, in __new__
    return cls.registries[db_name]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: 'odoodb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 417, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 191, in load_module_graph
    model_names = registry.load(cr, package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 222, in load
    model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 521, in _build_model
    raise TypeError("Model %r does not exist in registry." % name)
TypeError: Model 'product.product' does not exist in registry.
2020-05-09 10:51:52,553 15798 INFO odoodb werkzeug: 10.0.2.2 - - [09/May/2020 10:51:52] "GET /web HTTP/1.1" 500 - 9 0.005 0.032
2020-05-09 10:51:52,556 15798 ERROR odoodb werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 60, in __new__
    return cls.registries[db_name]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: 'odoodb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 306, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 294, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 439, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 142, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1287, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1257, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/middleware/shared_data.py", line 220, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1439, in dispatch
    odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/__init__.py", line 104, in registry
    return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 62, in __new__
    return cls.new(db_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 417, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 191, in load_module_graph
    model_names = registry.load(cr, package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 222, in load
    model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 521, in _build_model
    raise TypeError("Model %r does not exist in registry." % name)
TypeError: Model 'product.product' does not exist in registry. - - -
2020-05-09 10:51:52,806 15798 INFO odoodb odoo.modules.loading: loading 1 modules... 
2020-05-09 10:51:52,815 15798 INFO odoodb odoo.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.01s, 0 queries 
2020-05-09 10:51:52,831 15798 INFO odoodb odoo.modules.loading: loading 58 modules... 
2020-05-09 10:51:52,831 15798 WARNING odoodb odoo.modules.loading: Transient module states were reset 
2020-05-09 10:51:52,831 15798 ERROR odoodb odoo.modules.registry: Failed to load registry 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 60, in __new__
    return cls.registries[db_name]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: 'odoodb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 417, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 191, in load_module_graph
    model_names = registry.load(cr, package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 222, in load
    model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 521, in _build_model
    raise TypeError("Model %r does not exist in registry." % name)
TypeError: Model 'product.product' does not exist in registry.
2020-05-09 10:51:52,833 15798 INFO odoodb werkzeug: 10.0.2.2 - - [09/May/2020 10:51:52] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 - 9 0.003 0.028
2020-05-09 10:51:52,836 15798 ERROR odoodb werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 60, in __new__
    return cls.registries[db_name]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: 'odoodb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 306, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 294, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 439, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 142, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1287, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1257, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/middleware/shared_data.py", line 220, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1439, in dispatch
    odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/__init__.py", line 104, in registry
    return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 62, in __new__
    return cls.new(db_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 417, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 191, in load_module_graph
    model_names = registry.load(cr, package)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 222, in load
    model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 521, in _build_model
    raise TypeError("Model %r does not exist in registry." % name)
TypeError: Model 'product.product' does not exist in registry. - - -
```

Comment: Did you add a dependence to `product` module in the manifest file?

Comment: @Kenly I am new ar odoo, never heard of manifest file. What should I add there? I opened it up, and I need to type near ```depends``` product? I need to inherit the product template from ```webiste_sale``` module in odoo

Comment: A file named  `__manifest__.py` inside the module folder. please add the `depend` section to you question.

Comment: @Kenly Yeah, thanks. Now it does not crash. But is there any way to check, if inheritance was successful? ;)

Comment: Go to `Technical/Database Structure/Models` choose `product.product` and check if your module is listed in `In Apps` field or try to add some field and add it to the form view to be able to see it or

Comment: @Kenly Thank you for the reply, but my module is not present there. Apps there - ```product, sale, stock, stock_account, website_sale, website_sale_stock```

Comment: @Kenly Sorry, it was error in my module, and it wasn't loaded. That's why it wasn't in the list. Thank you :)

Comment: I am glad to help